# How to add padding to right to the string in python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

please help to add padding after values.
I'm trying to add right padding to the Gr no value in the excel output but not able to add.
please suggest.

```
po_nos =[]
dates = []
refs = []
totals = []
mat_codes = []
qtys = [] 
vendor_no = []
inv_amt = []
order_no = []
reference = []
gr_no= []
distance = []
dispatch = []
mode = []
address = []
padding = 5

for pth in paths:
 doc = pdfplumber.open(pth)
 page = doc.pages[0]
 token = page.extract_text().splitlines()
 vendor = token[5][14:][:35]
 #add = token[34][39:]
 #GR No = token[35][48:][:5]
 data = [i for i in token if 'Invoice No:' in i][0].split(' ')
 data1 = [i for i in token if 'Ref:' in i][0].split(' ')
 data2 = [i for i in token if 'Order' in i][0].split(' ')
 data3 = [i for i in token if 'GR No' in i][0].split(' ')
 #data3 = '{0:>2}'.format(gr_no)
 #data3= data3[2].str.pad(5, side ='right')
 data3 = [i for i in data3 if 'GR No'].str.pad(2, side='right')
 print(data3)
 data4 = [i for i in token if 'Distance' in i][0]
 data5 = [i for i in token if 'Mode of Transportation:' in i][0].split(' ')
 data6 = [i for i in token if 'Name and Address' in i][0]
 data7 = [i for i in token if 'PO No:' in i][0].split(' ')
 data7 = [i for i in data7 if i!='']
 ref = data[2]
 po_no = data7[11]
 refe = data1[7]
 order = data2[-9]
 gr = data3[2]
 mod = data5[15]
 dist= data4[49:53]
 add =data6[39:]
 date = data[5]
 idx = [i for i, j in enumerate(token) if j[:5] == 'Total'][0]
 total = token[idx].split(' ')[2]
 inv = token[idx].split(' ')[6]
 token = token[17:idx]
 token = [i for i in token if I[0] in ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10']]
 mat_code = [i.split(' ')[1] for I in token]
 qty = [i.split(' ')[-8] for I in token]
 po_nos.append([po_no]* Len(token))
 mat_codes.append(mat_code)
 qtys.append(qty)
 address.append([add]* len(token))
 distance.append([dist]* Len(token))
 totals.append([total]* Len(token))
 refs.append([ref] * Len(token))
 dates.append([date] * Len(token))
 vendor_no.append([vendor] * Len(token))
 inv_amt.append([inv] * Len(token))
 reference. Append([refe] * Len(token))
 order_no.append([order] * Len(token))
 gr_no.append([gr] * Len(token))
 mode. Append([mod]* Len(token))
```

Excepted Output
SNOI2203727     0 Km
SFLR325225SAM   0 Km

But i'm getting below
SNOI2203727     Km D
SFLR325225SAM   0 Km
SFLR324710SAM   0 Km
SNOI2204068     Km D

Answer (score 0):

To add blank spaces to a string you can use:

```
my_str = 'Hello' 
spaces_number = 5
my_str += ' ' * spaces_number
```

If all values must have the same length:

```
my_str = 'Hello' 
max_length = 15
my_str = my_str.ljust(max_length)
```